# ng-map change the color of the shape dynamically

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I'm using NgMap and angular 1 to display a google map, and draw various shapes on it.
I'm trying to change the color of the shape dynamically, by changing a scope variable.

In the template I have:

```
<shape id="circle" name="circle" fill-color='{{circle.color}}' stroke-color='{{circle.color}}' stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-weight="2" center="[41,-87]" radius="4000" editable="false">
</shape>
```

and in the controller I create an object:

```
function CircleColorTestController($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.circle = {
        color: '#00FF00'
    };

    var colors = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'];
    var i = 0;

    $interval(function() {
        $scope.circle.color = colors[i];
        console.log('Changing color to: ' + $scope.circle.color);
        ++i;
        if (i > 2) {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Check out this plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/nx5i5h

The color of the circle should change every second, but it remains green.
Is it even possible with NgMap? Is it a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: No bug in your code , fill-color attribute is changing . But it is not getting changed because its not a css attribute. fill-color is used as a configuraton attritube.

Comment: Ok thanks, well it's not the best api then. It should be consistent, either all parameters should provide real time bindin or none of them. (e.g. binding position or radius works)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that `fill-color` is not an angularjs directive that's why it not provide real time binding with scope variable.

Here is alternative way to create functionality that you want

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngMap'])
  .controller('CircleColorTestController', CircleColorTestController);

CircleColorTestController.$inject = ['$scope', '$interval'];

function CircleColorTestController($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.circle = {
    color: 'red'
  };
  var colors = ['#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF'];
  var i = 0;
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.circle.visible = colors[i];
    ++i;
    if (i > 2) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script data-require="ng-map@*" data-semver="1.7.12" src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CircleColorTestController">
  <div map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
    <ng-map center="41,-87" zoom="11">
      <shape id="circle" ng-if="circle.visible == '#FF0000'" name="circle" fill-color='#FF0000' stroke-color='#FF0000' stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-weight="2" center="[41,-87]" radius="4000" editable="false">
      </shape>

      <shape id="circle" ng-if="circle.visible == '#0000FF'" name="circle" fill-color='#0000FF' stroke-color='#0000FF' stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-weight="2" center="[41,-87]" radius="4000" editable="false">
      </shape>

      <shape id="circle" ng-if="circle.visible == '#00FF00'" name="circle" fill-color='#00FF00' stroke-color='#00FF00' stroke-opacity="0.8" stroke-weight="2" center="[41,-87]" radius="4000" editable="false">
      </shape>

    </ng-map>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I accepted your answer, but in my application I chose a different solution. I get the map instance with `NgMap.getMap(...)` and find the circle instance with the correct ID in the shape array of the map instance, and call a `circle.set('fill-color', '#FF0000');` on the instance.

Answer (score 0):

nagyf's solution works:

```
NgMap.getMap().then(map=>{map.shapes.circle.set('fillColor', '#FF0000')})
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/8m0gU1wqUETR8IjDoqvc?p=preview